# Tasks not starting for Airflow running inside a container

Tags: docker, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm trying to get Airflow up and running within a container and used the image available [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/puckel/docker-airflow/). I found that although the DAG gets into running state (on the UI), the tasks within the DAG seem to be waiting indefinitely and never actually get triggered.
Given that some of the steps given in the documentation are optional, I followed these steps in order to get the example DAGs up and running within my container -

*Pulled the image from dockerhub*

```
docker pull puckel/docker-airflow
```

*Triggered Airflow with default settings, which should start it with Sequential Executor*

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -e LOAD_EX=y puckel/docker-airflow
```

I'm relatively new to setting up Airflow and dockers, although I have worked on Airflow in the past. So, it's possible that I am missing something very basic here, since no one else seems to be facing the same issue. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The sequential executor is not a scheduler, so it only runs jobs that are created manually, from the UI or the run command. Certain kinds of tasks won't run in the sequential executor, I think its SubdagOperators that won't. While honestly it should be picking up dummy, bash, or python tasks, you may save time figuring it out if you run the scheduler and the local executor and a db. Puckel has an example docker compose file, https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried running the local executor and now, I can see the webserver and postgres containers running (using the docker ps command). After logging into the container (using /bin/bash to get to the shell), I tried the `airflow initdb` command and it failed, saying that it could not create a Fernet object. Moreover, I cannot see the sample DAGs on the UI as well now. Is there something really basic that I'm missing here? Nobody else seems to be facing this issue.

Comment: @SHASHWATSHUKLA the entrypoint.sh should have already tried to init the database.https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/script/entrypoint.sh#L72 ; I think your fernet key failure comes from missing config files settings or missing environment config overrides for the fernet key. The entrypoint generates a new and unique one each run https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/script/entrypoint.sh#L16 which can be a problem https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/issues/39